# How to compare two files having similar content

Tags: unix

I have two files which could have similar content (i.e. similar lines, but present in different rows). I tried `diff`, but it compares every line, but I want them to treat it as equal even if it is present in any row in the file. The following is a semantically equal file.

```
fileA

one
two
three
four

fileB

two
three
four
one
```

Comment: Why not just sort them how you like first and then diff?

Comment: why not manually split it into 2 files, then compare them?

Comment: They are in 2 files (fileA, fileB)

Comment: How do I sort and compare in a single step